# flutter : put TextEditingController in json body

Tags: json, flutter, woocommerce

dears,

I'm traying to catch value of TextEditingController to send it like this :-

```
 final firstName = TextEditingController();
  var data2 = {
    "shipping": {
      "address_1": firstName, // problem here don't accept this value ??
    }
  };
```

as json

```
 updateUser() async {
   user = await wooCommerce.updateCustomer(id: 2, data: data2); //id (int) , data (Map<dynamic,dynamic>)
    setState(() {});
  }
```

"address_1": firstName, given error to me with message
(X) the instance member can't be accessed in an initializer

so how to catch this value of text ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `firstnameController.text`:

```
final firstnameController = TextEditingController();

...

var data2 = {
  "shipping": {
    "address_1": firstnameController.text, // problem here don't accept this value ??
  }
};
```

Comment: The instance member 'firstName' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Comment: Can you provide the full source code of your Widget? Where do create this variable data2?

Comment: its only can accept :   
var data2 = {
    "shipping": {
      "address_1": "USA",
    }
  };

Comment: it given to me error when i try to post here like long code

Comment: Where do you create this variable data2? Can you provide the source code as a DartPad? https://dartpad.dartlang.org/